# How to convert list of dictionary to dict using the list of dict values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I dont know how to start with this and would love to any help.

i have this list of dict:

```
mylist_of_dict = 
[{"plat": "Linux",
  "os_name": "Android",
}, {
  "plat": "Linux",
  "os_name": "Chrome OS",
}, {
  "plat": "Win32",
  "os_name": "Windows",
}]
```

My main goal is to transform it into this dict where the plat key value is now the key and the os_name are values:

```
{'Linux':["Android", "Chrome OS"],
'Win32': ["Windows",]}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
out = {}
for d in mylist_of_dict:
    out.setdefault(d["plat"], []).append(d["os_name"])

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{"Linux": ["Android", "Chrome OS"], "Win32": ["Windows"]}
```

Comment: I've never seen `setdefault` before, always resorting to an if statement. You've changed my life :D

Comment: You can also use `collections.defaultdict` that uses the `setdefault` method internally.