# Convert list of dict into single dict with lists as values

Tags: list, dictionary, ansible

I have the following list of dicts

```json
    "scott_adams_list": [
        {
            "name": "Pointy-haired-Boss",
            "level": "Management"
        },
        {
            "name": "Dogbert",
            "level": "Management"
        },
        {
            "name": "Mega-Boss",
            "level": "Management"
        },
        {
            "name": "Dilbert",
            "level": "Staff"
        },
        {
            "name": "Wally",
            "level": "Staff"
        },
        {
            "name": "Alice",
            "level": "Staff"
        },
        {
            "name": "Asok",
            "level": "Staff"
        }
    ]
```

I would like to convert this to a single dictionary as follows

```json
"scott_adams_dict": {
    "Management": ["Pointy-haired-Boss", "Dogbert", "Mega-Boss"],
    "Staff": ["Dilbert", "Wally", "Alice", "Asok"]
}
```

I've tried the following

```yaml
    - name: create single dictionary
      set_fact:
        dilbert: "{{ dict(scott_adams_list | json_query(dilbert_query)) }}"
      vars:
        dilbert_query: >
          [].[ ds_type, ds_id ]
```

This returns only the first items for each *level* type, that is

```json
    "dilbert": {
        "Management": "Pointy-haired-Boss",
        "Staff": "Dilbert"
    }
```

I then tried to loop through the items in the *scott_adams_list* but, that's throwing an error

```yaml
    - name: create single dictionary
      set_fact:
        dilbert: "{{ dict(scott_adams_list | json_query(dilbert_query)) }}"
      vars:
        dilbert_query: >
          [].[ item.ds_type, item.ds_id ]
      loop: "{{ scott_adams_list }}"
```

I've also looked at
[How to convert list of dictionary to dict using the list of dict values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74180023/how-to-convert-list-of-dictionary-to-dict-using-the-list-of-dict-values)
but was unable to make it work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a self explanatory `test.yml` playbook with intermediate details:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    scott_adams_list: [
      {
        "name": "Pointy-haired-Boss",
        "level": "Management"
      },
      {
        "name": "Dogbert",
        "level": "Management"
      },
      {
        "name": "Mega-Boss",
        "level": "Management"
      },
      {
        "name": "Dilbert",
        "level": "Staff"
      },
      {
        "name": "Wally",
        "level": "Staff"
      },
      {
        "name": "Alice",
        "level": "Staff"
      },
      {
        "name": "Asok",
        "level": "Staff"
      }
    ]

    grouped_by_level: "{{ scott_adams_list | groupby('level') }}"
    levels_list: "{{ grouped_by_level | map(attribute=0) }}"
    list_of_users_list: "{{ grouped_by_level | map(attribute=1) | map('map', attribute='name') }}"
    scott_adams_dict: "{{ dict(levels_list | zip(list_of_users_list)) }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Group entries by level
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: grouped_by_level

    - name: Extract list of levels
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: levels_list

    - name: Extract list of users list
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: list_of_users_list

    - name: Put everything together as a dict
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: scott_adams_dict
```

Which gives as a result:

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yml 

PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Group entries by level] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "grouped_by_level": [
        [
            "Management",
            [
                {
                    "level": "Management",
                    "name": "Pointy-haired-Boss"
                },
                {
                    "level": "Management",
                    "name": "Dogbert"
                },
                {
                    "level": "Management",
                    "name": "Mega-Boss"
                }
            ]
        ],
        [
            "Staff",
            [
                {
                    "level": "Staff",
                    "name": "Dilbert"
                },
                {
                    "level": "Staff",
                    "name": "Wally"
                },
                {
                    "level": "Staff",
                    "name": "Alice"
                },
                {
                    "level": "Staff",
                    "name": "Asok"
                }
            ]
        ]
    ]
}

TASK [Extract list of levels] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "levels_list": [
        "Management",
        "Staff"
    ]
}

TASK [Extract list of users list] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "list_of_users_list": [
        [
            "Pointy-haired-Boss",
            "Dogbert",
            "Mega-Boss"
        ],
        [
            "Dilbert",
            "Wally",
            "Alice",
            "Asok"
        ]
    ]
}

TASK [Put everything together as a dict] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "scott_adams_dict": {
        "Management": [
            "Pointy-haired-Boss",
            "Dogbert",
            "Mega-Boss"
        ],
        "Staff": [
            "Dilbert",
            "Wally",
            "Alice",
            "Asok"
        ]
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 2):

In python:

```py
obj = {
  "scott_adams_list": [
      {
          "name": "Pointy-haired-Boss",
          "level": "Management"
      },
      {
          "name": "Dogbert",
          "level": "Management"
      },
      {
          "name": "Mega-Boss",
          "level": "Management"
      },
      {
          "name": "Dilbert",
          "level": "Staff"
      },
      {
          "name": "Wally",
          "level": "Staff"
      },
      {
          "name": "Alice",
          "level": "Staff"
      },
      {
          "name": "Asok",
          "level": "Staff"
      }
  ]
}


def change_schema(obj):
  new_obj = {}

  for name in obj:
    new_obj[name] = {
      "Management": [],
      "Staff": []
    }

    for name_level_obj in obj[name]:
      new_obj[name][name_level_obj["level"]].append(name_level_obj["name"])

  return new_obj

print(change_schema(obj))
```

generates:

```
{
  'scott_adams_list': {
     'Management': ['Pointy-haired-Boss', 'Dogbert', 'Mega-Boss'], 
     'Staff': ['Dilbert', 'Wally', 'Alice', 'Asok']
   }
}
```

Comment: Op is looking for a solution inside an ansible playbook.

Comment: But a very good input if one is going to [Develop his own Filter Plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#developing-filter-plugins).

Comment: Missing the details to be a custom filter though.

Comment: Thanks for the same in Python, Trying to find time to learn Python so this is good to have

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter [community.general.lists_mergeby](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_abstract_informations_merging_lists_of_dictionaries.html#merging-lists-of-dictionaries). However, the attributes *name* must be converted to lists first

```yaml
  sa_query: '[].{level: level, name: [name]}'
  sa_list: "{{ [scott_adams_list|json_query(sa_query), []]|
               community.general.lists_mergeby('level', list_merge='append') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  sa_list:
    - level: Management
      name: [Pointy-haired-Boss, Dogbert, Mega-Boss]
    - level: Staff
      name: [Dilbert, Wally, Alice, Asok]
```

The conversion to a dictionary is trivial

```yaml
  sa_dict: "{{ sa_list|items2dict(key_name='level', value_name='name') }}"
```

gives what you want

```yaml
  sa_dict:
    Management: [Pointy-haired-Boss, Dogbert, Mega-Boss]
    Staff: [Dilbert, Wally, Alice, Asok]
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    scott_adams_list:
      - {level: Management, name: Pointy-haired-Boss}
      - {level: Management, name: Dogbert}
      - {level: Management, name: Mega-Boss}
      - {level: Staff, name: Dilbert}
      - {level: Staff, name: Wally}
      - {level: Staff, name: Alice}
      - {level: Staff, name: Asok}

    sa_query: '[].{level: level, name: [name]}'
    sa_list: "{{ [scott_adams_list|json_query(sa_query), []]|
                 community.general.lists_mergeby('level', list_merge='append') }}"
    sa_dict: "{{ sa_list|items2dict(key_name='level', value_name='name') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: sa_list|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: sa_dict|to_yaml
```